# Understanding Web API DOM interfaces

Tags: javascript, dom, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to learn more about Web APIs. Reading about them I see that among the wide variety of web API's there's the DocumentObjectModel API. Reading about the DOM specifications, I find a list of a lot of DOM interfaces. This makes me feel a little upset. In my ignorance, I think that an API should contain only one interface (only one set of functions and properties), here I find a list of interfaces...and that's the first thing that I don't understand.

Moreover, I usually interact with the DOM using notations like

```
document.getElementById("idname");
document.getElementByTagName("tagname");
etc ect
```

I see that some of these DOM interfaces have names that I already know, like "Document" or "Window", I use them (like in the previous two lines of code) but I use them not capitalized ("document" rather than "Document"). I don't understand if there is a link beetwen "document" and "Document", for example...

Finally, I noticed that querying for the global object (in the browser console, for example, simply typing the keyword "this") I have in response an object that (I guess) contains all the properties and functions (or methods) of the global object. And among them there are also functions that have the same names listed in the DOM interfaces list. And that's simply another thing that I noticed that I'm not able to explain.

So, can you help me to understand more deeply DOM API?

Comment: There's a lot of questions here ... To ease your pain with `Document` and `Window`, enter `typeof Document` and `document instanceof Document` to the console, the results might shed some light over that question.

Comment: @Teemu I did it. I suppose that document is an instance of Document. But I didn't create this instance. Is it created "automatically"?

Answer (score 4):

Those things arise from an interaction of javascript and the DOM specifications.

The capital-letter `Window` and `Document` are interfaces defined by the [DOM](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-document) and [HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#the-window-object) specs.

In Javascript, when executed in a browser environment, an instance of `Window` is the global object and `Window` is its prototype. `document` and `window` are getter properties defined by those interfaces. Since the window is the [global object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-overview) (the top-level `this`) and variable name resolution walks up the scope chain and finally lands at the global object if it cannot find it elsewhere `window` will eventually resolve to `<global object>.window`. Which is the attribute defined on the `Window` interface, which returns the window instance itself, which also is the global object. It is self-referential.

So the global object ends up having properties defined by javascript, by the dom/html specs and inherited from the prototypes also defined by those various specs.

Some prototypes are also exposed as named properties in the global object and not just the prototype chain of the instances. This is convenient for `instanceof` checks and feature detection. Some constructors are also exposed, e.g. `new Image()` creates a new instance of `HTMLImageElement` the same way `document.createElement("img")` would.

Additional Document instances can created via various constructors or factories such as `DOMParser`. Additional Window instances might be accessed through frames, the page's opener or spawned child windows.

Looking at the window object with a debugger may help.

Comment: I have the impression you said something that can help me to clarify my doubts, but maybe my english does not help me and I still have doubts. 

The global object is an instance of Window. But to me is odd to see that Window itself (the constructor, I think we can identify it as a constructor...) is part of the global object itself. It's difficult for me to understand how is possible that the global object is instance of Window and at the same time it has Window inside itself.

Comment: The constructor *object* is just assigned to the property `window.Window` after the `window` has been constructed. Run this in the console: `Object.getPrototypeOf(window).constructor == Window`. It's only placed there for convenience so you can `window instanceof Window`. Your javascript only runs after the browser is done after building the the standard objects.